# Parsing XML in q (KX)

Tags: kdb

Am trying to parse XML file in q. Am able to flatten the file but, further i could not extract the result. Below is the data set.

````
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
   Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
   </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu> ```

Below is the code i have tried so far.

file: read0 `$"File.xml"
file1: raze file
file2: enlist file2
````

Unable to parse the records further. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I would say q is not the way to go in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small utility [qxml](https://github.com/rianoc/qxml) previously using [embedPy](https://code.kx.com/q/ml/embedpy/) to extract XML data in to a kdb+ process.

```
q)\l qxml.q
q)menu:.qxml.read[`:menu.xml]
q)menu[`breakfast_menu;`food]
name                         price   description                             ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
"Belgian Waffles"            "$5.95" "Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with ..
"Strawberry Belgian Waffles" "$7.95" "Light Belgian waffles covered with stra..
```

Other options could be:

- These C based projects [xml](https://github.com/dstrachan/xml) and [qexpat](https://github.com/felixlungu/qexpat) are also available on Github (I have not tested them).
- kdb+ can natively parse JSON using [.j.k](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotj/#jk-deserialize) if you can convert the file first.

Answer (score 2):

For a pure q solution, you can try using this [xml.q](https://gist.github.com/jonathonmcmurray/882c56381582a554f4f8e6e141ee51aa) (translated from [xml.k](https://a.kx.com/a/k/examples/xml.k) here). This is not a complete translation (xml.k can parse & encode XML, here I've only translated the parsing) and may not be as efficient or robust as other solutions using C/python, but it seems to allow parsing your example XML (saved as `breakfast.xml`):

```
q)b:.xml.dx raze read0`:breakfast.xml
q)b
`breakfast_menu
((`food;((`name;"Belgian Waffles");(`price;"$5.95");(`description;"Two of our..
q)b[0]
`breakfast_menu
q)b[1]
`food ((`name;"Belgian Waffles");(`price;"$5.95");(`description;"Two of our f..
`food ((`name;"Strawberry Belgian Waffles");(`price;"$7.95");(`description;"L..
q)
```

Note that due to the indentation of lines etc. in the xml file there may be some extra padding in some of the strings after parsing. You can use [trim](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/trim/) to remove this e.g.

```
q)b:trim .xml.dx raze read0`:breakfast.xml
```