# Parsing XML messages in kdb

Tags: xml, kdb

I have a table containing an XML message published to us as a symbol. I need to parse this into a table. Are there any available libraries for doing this or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: There are some useful answers on the same question posted recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944905/parsing-xml-in-q-kx

Comment: To some extent. I decided to use embedPy after all an use the ElementTree library from there. At first I went on to use string manipulation to extract the fields I needed.